# Having difficulty adding a second route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

So I'm new to VueJs so excuse any mistakes I make here. I have a simple front end application, which is meant to be two pages long. There's an index route and a game route. The game route takes a path variable name that is meant to be displayed on the screen.

I've added the route, imported the components but whenever I try accessing the URL it just displays the index page. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Here is my index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import home from '@/components/home'//index
import game from '@/components/game'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: home
    },
    {
      path:'/game/:name',
      name:'game',
      component:game
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is my game.vue file (It's incomplete, I just want to get it to load first):

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid m=0 p=0">
    <div id="theGame" class="full-page p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Welcome {{route.params.name}}</h1>
    </div>

    </div>
</div> 
</template>
<script>
const choices = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            name:'game',
            yourChoice: null,
            aiChoice:null,
            yourScore:0,
            aiScore:0,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        startPlay : function(choice){
            this.yourChoice=choice;
            this.aiChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];
            this.gamePlay();
        },
        gamePlay: function(){
            if(this.yourChoice=='Rock' && this.aiChoice=='Scissors'){
                this.yourScore++;
            }
            else if(this.yourChoice=='Paper' && this.aiChoice=='Rock'){
                this.yourScore++;
            }
            else if(this.yourChoice=='Scissors' && this.aiChoice=='Paper'){
                this.yourScore++;
            }
            else if(this.yourChoice==this.aiChoice){
                console.log("Draw");
            }
            else{
                this.aiScore++;
            } 
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: how do you visit that url?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim if running on localhost it looks something like "localhost:8080/game/bob".

Comment: You should go to the new route with either a `router-link` or a `router.push({ path: 'your-route' })`, check here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using hash mode by default that allows to access the routes prefixed by `#` sign :

```
localhost:8080/#/game/bob
```

if you want to access it like `localhost:8080/game/bob` you should add history mode to the router definition:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: home
    },
    {
      path:'/game/:name',
      name:'game',
      component:game
    }
  ]
})
```